# Find antiderivative of $8\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I was tasked with finding the antiderivative of $8\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)$

This is what I have $$4\sin^4(2x)-\int24\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)\,dx$$

I don't know the step after that.

Comment: *Hint*: what's $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin(2x)\right]$ ?

Comment: what is $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)^4$?

Answer (score 2):

Just observe

$$\int 8\sin^3(2x)\cos (2x)\,dx=4\int\sin^3(2x)\cos (2x)\cdot2\,dx=4\int u^3\,du=...$$